# Generate irregular blob Shape in java

Tags: java, random, shapes

I'm trying to generate a random irregular `java.awt.Shape` blob, something like the examples in the second answer (the one by Paul Gaborit) to [this question on tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126144/how-to-draw-a-irregular-circleshape).

If there is a way to start with an `Ellipse2D` and then modify that similar to how it is done in TeX in that answer, great.

Otherwise, maybe I could do something like this?:

```
public Shape createShape(int pointCount, double max_deviation, int median_radius,
                         int[] center)
{
    int[][] pathPoints = new int[pointCount][2];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i=0;i<pointCount;i++)
    {
        double angle = (2*Math.PI/((double)pointCount))*((double)i);
        double temp_deviation = (0.5-rand.nextDouble())*2.0*max_deviation;
        double temp_radius = median_radius+temp_deviation;
        int x = (int) Math.round(temp_radius*Math.cos(angle));
        int y = (int) Math.round(temp_radius*Math.sin(angle));
        pathPoints[i] = new int[] {x+center[0],y+center[1]};
    }
    // somehow make pathPoints into a Shape with smooth curves
    return shape;
}
```

Still, that would only produce a crude initial blob. It would be nice if I could then introduce fined grained random ripples in that random shape.